# Are these Infinite Series Representations of Special Functions?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, special-functions

I am not sure how to google the answer for this question. Anyway, in trying to compute the velocity of a charged particle in an electromagnetic field, I came across these two infinite series (Maclaurin series, generating functions):

> $$F_1(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{(2k+1)!}$$
>
> $$F_2(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{(2k+2)!}$$

Obviously these are similar to sine and cosine, which is what I thought they were at first until I noticed that the exponents were wrong.

**What I Have Tried:** I think we have that $$xF_1(x^2)=\sin(x)$$

Does this imply that $$F_1(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}?$$

I think so, but I feel like this "proof" is too hand-wavey. For $F_2(x)$, I suspect there is a similar relationship to cosine, but I'm not sure about how to get the factorials to behave.

**EDIT:** I think for $F_2(x)$ we have $$x^2F_2(x^2)=1-\cos(x)$$ $$\implies F_2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{x})}{x}$$

Comment: Your conjecture about $F_1$ is almost correct. Note that $\sin z = z F_2(z^2) + z$. As to $F_2$,   we have $z^2F_2(z^2) + 1 = \cos z$ which gives a similar formula for $F_2$..

Comment: Oh yeah it should start at k=0; I don't know why I typed k=1; thank you for catching that!

Comment: WolframAlpha seems to bear both answers out.

Comment: Thanks so much again! I wanted to check Wolfram but I still need to teach myself Mathematica